# Send image data with FormData as a png file

Tags: angular

I use `angular2-img-cropper` and given a cropped image in data url format I would like to convert it to a PNG file and send it to the server:

```js
cropped(bounds: Bounds) {
  // convert this.data.image to a PNG file
  // send it to the server with form data
}

fileChangeListener($event) {
  const image: any = new Image();
  const file: File = $event.target.files[0];
  const myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  const that = this;
  myReader.onloadend = function (loadEvent: any) {
    image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
    that.cropper.setImage(image);
  };
  myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<img-cropper #cropper (onCrop)="cropped($event)" [image]="data" [settings]="cropperSettings"></img-cropper>
```

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Don't send it as PNG. Send it as Base64, then convert it to PNG on the server

Comment: server is outside of my office and is under develop with another team